# Is any holomorphic $p$-form on a Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ manifold closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In [Fujiki's 78 paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01403162), p.227, Corollary 1.7. (1), there is

> Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$, then every holomorphic $p$-form on $X$ is closed.

In Kodaira & Morrow's book *complex manifolds* p.115, Proposition 5.5, it is proved that on a compact Kähler manifold $X$, every holomorphic $p$-form is $d$-closed.
However I doubt this statement may be false in the Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ case, but I have no counter-example. The author Fujiki refer the proof to Ueno's 75 book *Classification theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex spaces*, but I can't find the proof there.

Does anyone has a simple proof of it or a counter-example to the statement above?

Comment: This is because the Frölicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$ for compact complex manifolds in Fujiki class $\mathcal{C}$ as well. In particular $d_1^{p,0} : E_1^{p,0} \to E_1^{p+1,0}$, which is the usual differential $d : H^0(X,\Omega_X^p) \to H^0(X,\Omega_X^{p+1})$, vanishes.

Comment: @HYL, what a nice explanation! So holomorphic $p$-form is closed on any compact complex manifold with Frolicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$. By the way, does $d : H^0(X,\Omega_X^p) \to H^0(X,\Omega_X^{p+1})$ mean $\partial : H^0(X,\Omega_X^p) \to H^0(X,\Omega_X^{p+1})$?

Comment: On holomorphic forms, $d$ and $\partial $ are the same.

Comment: For the record: it is Corollary 9.5 on p. 101 of Ueno's book.